# AddChild to the stage only once when revisiting frame

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, flash-cs6, stage, addchild

I have two frames.

In the first frame you can click a button to go to the next frame. In the first frame I want to add `menu1` to the stage just once. If we go to the next frame and then back to the first frame, the `menu1` should not be created again since it is already on the stage.

My problem is, when I go back from frame 2 to frame 1, it keeps adding `menu1` copies to the stage.

Here is my current code:

```
stop();

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Stage;

var menu1:Loader = new Loader();
var request1:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("MENU1.swf");
menu1.load(request1);

if (stage.contains(menu1)){

}
else 
{
    addChild(menu1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it still keeps adding the menu every time, is because your if condition will always be `false`.

There are two lines to point out why that is the case:

```
var menu1:Loader = new Loader();
```

In the above line, you are creating a brand new Loader() object and assigning it to the var `menu1`

```
if (stage.contains(menu1)){
```

in the above line, you're checking if `menu1` is currently on the stage

Since the first line runs every time you visit this frame,  a brand new object is created every time.  That new object doesn't exist on the stage yet (the previous one does) so the `if` conditional will always evaluate as `false`.

To remedy this, you can do the following:

```
var menu1:Loader; //just define the var here, don't assign anything yet

//if menu1 doesn't have a value
if(!menu1){

    //create a new Loader only if one doesn't exist yet
    menu1 = new Loader();
    var request1:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("MENU1.swf");
    menu1.load(request1);
    addChild(menu1);
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm, but the problem now occurred is when from frame 2 to frame 1, the swf from frame 2 is overlapping the frame 1. So do the button

Comment: hello, why is my object doesnt show up when I back? Its really confusing

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new question with your frame 2 code and a more detailed explanation of how it should work and what the problem is.